# How to install JavaScript Eclipse platform on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, eclipse, javascript

I `sudo apt-get install eclipse` installed Eclipse on my Ubuntu 12.0.4 server, by checking I found it is a classic platform. So, how can I make it as a JavaScript IDE? I followed http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro, but the page said there is no Market Place for classic platform. So, could you help me this out? I am a beginner of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

The Eclipse in Ubuntu official repo is usually outdated (3.7.2 in Precise, the latest is 4.2.2). I prefer installing Eclipse manually. Download Eclipse [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/). I don't know what MPC is, but since it says MPC is included in all of the packages available from the Eclipse download page (except the Classic Package), you can just pick one version, say 
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers. I use Eclipse for Android development, so I choose Eclipse for Mobile Developers. First delete Eclipse you installed via apt, then follow these instructions.

1. Download `eclipse-mobile-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz`
2. Unzip the archive.

   ```
   tar xzvf eclipse-mobile-juno-SR2-linux-gtk.tar.gz
   ```
3. Move the folder to you desired location.

   ```
   mv eclipse ~/bin/
   ```
4. Create a symlink in /usr/bin

   ```
   sudo ln -s ~/bin/eclipse/eclipse /usr/bin/eclipse
   ```
5. Create a gnome menu item.

   ```
   sudo -H gedit /usr/share/applications/eclipse.desktop
   ```

   copy these into gedit and save the file.

   ```
    [Desktop Entry]  
    Encoding=UTF-8  
    Name=Eclipse  
    Comment=Eclipse IDE  
    Exec=eclipse  
    Icon=~/bin/eclipse/icon.xpm  
    Terminal=false  
    Type=Application  
    Categories=GNOME;Application;Development;  
    StartupNotify=true
   ```
6. Run Eclipse from the terminal for the first time
   `eclipse -clean &`

This will install Eclipse in your home folder which is my preferred, it's fine if you're the only user. If you want a system-wide install. You need some extra steps, follow the instructions in this [post](http://colinrrobinson.com/technology/install-eclipse-ubuntu/).

Comment: Good answer ;-) But the folder that is intended to use for software that doesn't come with the standard installation/repositories is `/opt`. You don't want the fiddle around in `/bin` because the package manager might replace/change something.

Comment: I didn't touch /bin. As I said, I put everything in home folder(~/bin, ~/src, ~/elisp and etc). It's just my personal preferences. I find it convenient and easy to organise.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I missed the `~` before `/bin` ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Personally I dont't use the Eclipse from the repositories because it gets outdated pretty quick. I [download](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) the package I need, extract it and place the `eclipse` folder into `/opt`.

To be able to launch that Eclipse using the dash, create a file `~/.local/share/applications/Eclipse.desktop` with the following content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Eclipse
GenericName=Programming
Comment=Eclipse  
Type=Application
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
```